# speed up LOAD DATA INFILE with duplicates - 250 GB

Tags: mysql, duplicates, innodb, load-data-infile

Am looking for advice about whether there is any way to speed up the import of  about 250 GB of data into a MySQL table (InnoDB) from eight source csv files of approx. 30 GB each.  The csv's have no duplicates within themselves, but do contain duplicates between files -- in fact some individual records appear in all 8 csv files.  So those duplicates need to be removed at some point in the process.  My current approach creates an empty table with a primary key, and then uses eight “LOAD DATA INFILE [...] IGNORE” statements to sequentially load each csv file, while dropping duplicate entries.  It works great on small sample files.  But with the real data, the first file takes about 1 hour to load, then the second takes more than 2 hours, the third one more than 5, the fourth one more than 9 hours, which is where I’m at right now.  It appears that as the table grows, the time required to compare the new data to the existing data is increasing... which of course makes sense.  But with four more files to go, it looks like it might take another 4 or 5 days to complete if I just let it run its course.

Would I be better off importing everything with no indexes on the table, and then removing duplicates after?  Or should I import each of the 8 csv's into separate temporary tables and then do a union query to create a new consolidated table without duplicates?  Or are those approaches going to take just as long?

Comment: There are too many intangibles here. Importing everything without an index, then sorting out the duplicates later will be faster overall than what you're doing now. Whether it's faster through intermediate tables is something you'll have to try.

Answer (score 0):

**Plan A**

You have a column for dedupping; lets call it `name`.

```
CREATE TABLE New (
    name ...,
    ...
    PRIMARY KEY (name) -- no other indexes
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Then, 1 csv at a time:

```
* Sort the csv by name (this makes any caching work better)

LOAD DATA ...
```

Yes, something similar to Plan A could be done with temp tables, but it might not be any faster.

**Plan B**

Sort all the csv files together (probably the unix "sort" can do this in a single command?).

Plan B is probably fastest, since it is extremely efficient in I/O.